# Python file-io code listing current folder path instead of the specified

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have the code:

```
import os
import sys

fileList = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
for file in fileList:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        print "File >> " + os.path.abspath(file)
    else:
        print "Dir >> " + os.path.abspath(file)
```

Located in my music folder ("/home/tom/Music")

When I call it with:

```
python test.py "/tmp"
```

I expected it to list my "/tmp" files and folders with the full path. But it printed lines like:

```
Dir >> /home/tom/Music/seahorse-gw2jNn
Dir >> /home/tom/Music/FlashXX9kV847
Dir >> /home/tom/Music/pulse-DcIEoxW5h2gz
```

This is, the correct file names, but the wrong path (and this files are not either in my Music folder).. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the full path to the file when you check for existence and print the path:

```
dir = sys.argv[1]

fileList = os.listdir(dir)
for file in fileList:
    file = os.path.join(dir, file)  # Get the full path to the file.
    # etc...
```

Comment: adding that line with `file = os.path(sys.argv[1], file)` give in this line: File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    file = os.path(sys.argv[1], file)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: by the way, with the current behavior looks like a bug: if I get the list of files from a folder, and it lists it like if it were in the current folder.. don't you think?

Comment: @Tom Brito: No, it's not a bug. `os.listdir` returns only the filename of the file, not the full path. When you pass a filename without an absolute path to `os.path.isfile` it is assumed that it is relative to the current working directoy. The same applies to `os.path.abspath`. You could claim that it is *annoying* that listdir returns the filenames without paths, but it's by design.

Comment: after some re-organization of the methods it worked.. I don't know why didn't worked before.. but anyway..